# IE 11 doesn't show favicon when accessing the sever through ipv6 address

Tags: internet-explorer, ipv6, favicon

I used express as my local server to test my web application. Everything 
was OK when i accessed the server using ipv4 address(localhost:8000) in IE 11 browser. However, when i accessed the server using ipv6 address([::1]:8000), everything worked well except IE didn't show favicon.

I checked the log information in debug mode in IE and found that IE didn't send request to require the favicon(confirm in express console that server didn't receive the request of requiring the favicon).

PS:I tried to access the icon directly using http://[::1]:8000/favicon.ico. It was OK.

Comment: I cleared cookies, cache... each time i tested.

Comment: localhost:8000 will use IPv6 by default, not IPv4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is because of IE bug. see link:  https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/961284/favicon-not-displayed-on-ipv6-literal-hostnames

**NOTE: localhost:8000 will use IPv6 by default, not IPv4.**

Make sure you have following code in `<head>`.
`<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">`
If you use IP address directly, IE will not try to access /favicon.ico.

Comment: Yes, You're right. I modified the host file and change localhost to ::1. Now IE can display favicon if i use localhost:8000. But I couldn't understand the modification. If i use ipv4 address, IE always display the favicon if i use 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000. Why is not working when i use ipv6 address directly?

Comment: @binjun.wang do you have a link element in the head?

Comment: It seems that it is because of IE bug. see link: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/961284/favicon-not-displayed-on-ipv6-literal-hostnames

Comment: Yes, i have link element in the head.